# Multilevel quote in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, quotes, multi-level

OK, this is perhaps stupidest question ever but bear with me....

How to make this work:

```
$("#basephoto").after(
  '<tr><td valign="bottom">Additional photo:</td>
       <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
       <td><div id="addphoto'+curupfld+'" class="browsebg">
         <p class="bpath"></p>
         <input onchange="fillBrowse(\"#addphoto'+curupfld+'\",this); validateExt(field);"  class="browse transfield" type="file" name="altphoto'+curupfld+'" size="40" />
         <span onclick="delImgField(this.id)" id="delbtn'+curupfld+'" class="abuttons delbtn"></span></div>
       </td>
   </tr>');
```

The part of interest:

```
onchange="fillBrowse(\"#addphoto'+curupfld+'\",this); validateExt(field);"
```

The problem starts at the "onchange". I can always make a function that calls these two and the solution would be:

```
$("#basephoto").after(
  '<tr>
     <td valign="bottom">Additional photo:</td>
     <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
     <td>
       <div id="addphoto'+curupfld+'" class="browsebg">
       <p class="bpath"></p>
       <input onchange=functionCaller("#addphoto'+curupfld+'",this) class="browse transfield" type="file" name="altphoto'+curupfld+'" size="40" />
       <span onclick="delImgField(this.id)" id="delbtn'+curupfld+'" class="abuttons delbtn"></span>
       </div>
      </td>
   </tr>');
```

This works, but if possible I would like to solve the problem rather than just use a workaround method.

Comment: Can you explain the desired behavior a little better?

Comment: It'd be *way* better to add all the event handlers with jQuery, since you're using it already anyway. That's a really hard-to-maintain mess as it is. Instead of that "HTML in a string" anti-pattern, use jQuery to build up elements incrementally.

Comment: Next time try and make your code slightly readable. I've sorted it out as best I could.

Comment: Oh, yes sorry about the mess;

@Pointy
already tried delgate() or on() and it didn't have any effect maybe I used wrong selector that contained these since the page includes php that than injects template file well I'm sure it can be fixed but I just didn't have nerves to figure it out

James Johnson
Browsers don't parse correctly \" or \' in this situation so I want to know if I made a mistake somewhere in the quota

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I  really don't know what you are really doing. But if you just wan't to write it in a more jQuery way.. This may help..

```
$('#basephoto').append('<tr />');
$('#basephoto tr').append(
    $('<td />')
        .attr('valign','bottom')
        .html('Additional photo:')
);
$('#basephoto tr').append(
    $('<td />')
        .html('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;')
);
$('#basephoto tr').append(
    $('<td />')
        .html(
            $('<div />')
            .attr({
                "id":"addphoto-"+curupld,
                "class":"browsebg"  
            })
            .html(
                $('<p />')
                    .attr('class','bpath')
                    .html('')
            )
        )
);
$('#addphoto-'+curupfld).append(
    $('<input />')
        .attr({
            "class":"browse transfield",
            "type":"file",
            "name":"altphoto-"+curupfld,
            "size":"40"
        })
        .change(function(){
            functionCaller('#addphoto-'+curupfld,this);
            validateExt(field);
        })
);
$('#addphoto-'+curupfld).append(
    $('<span />')
        .attr({
            "class":"abuttons delbtn",
            "id":"delbtn-"+curupfld
        })
        .click(function(){
            delImgField($(this).attr('id'));
        })
);
```

Check out this post to know more how to create elements using jQuery:

- http://mongsang-ga.tumblr.com/post/19914049827/how-to-create-a-element-in-jquery

> I guess you just need to add a line like this then to fix your
>   problem:
>
> ```
> $('#input_that_has_the_change_event').change(function(){
>     fillBrowse('#addphoto'+curupfld,this);
>     validateExt(field);
> });
> ```

*P.S.: Don't say it's stupid. I'm just like you before.. :]

Comment: No, I don't need it to look more jqueryish I already found a solution the second problem occurred. What I want to know is why doesn't my first code snippet work, is it because I messed up some quotes, the correct way to fix it if possible at all. Syntax is the question here.

Comment: How about just give your input an id or a class then add another jQuery line that like this: $('#input').change(function(){fillBrowse('#addphoto'+curupfld,this);validateExt(field);});

Comment: I did something like that. I just didn't assigned event on a selector via jQuery because I read somewhere that its performance wise a bad move because it scans the whole DOM tree to find a selector and that's why they made event handlers like live(), delegate(), on() that can narrow down the search an handle live injected elements.(I may be wrong about this but that's what I remembered at that moment) What I've done is create a function that calls these two and that's it. Because one function doesn't require level 3 quote marks like two and works just fine. See my third snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Use a template system like underscore. Maintainable, and easier to read/troubleshoot.

http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/

Example:

```
    <script id="templateA" type="text/template">
          <p>
                 Test stuff <a href="/home.html"><%= label %></a>
                 ...
          </p>
    </script>
...

<script type="javascript">
        var templateFunction = _.template($('#templateA').html());
        $('#someDivID').after(templateFunction({label: 'Here'}));
</script>
```

Comment: You are expecting too much of me, I'm a newbe and maybe not be skilled enough to use this and also I don't want to rewrite everything now ...

but even so you got me interested in this template thingy so I will pursue it for future projects

Comment: It really makes your projects a lot less work when you go back six months from now and need to modify things. Templates are the way to go, on your next project where you are dynamically generating content in js give it a try :)